# Group variable by "n" consecutive integers in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(var = 1:100)
```

I want to create a second variable, `group` that groups the values in `var` by `n` consecutive integers. So if `n` is equal to 1, it would return the same column as `var`. If `n=2`, it would return me:

```
  var   group
1:   1   1
2:   2   1
3:   3   2
4:   4   2
5:   5   3
6:   6   3
```

If `n=3`, it would return me:

```
  var   group
1:   1   1
2:   2   1
3:   3   1
4:   4   2
5:   5   2
6:   6   2
```

and so on. I would like to do this as flexibly as possibly.

Note that there could be repeated values:

```
  var   group
1:   1   1
2:   1   1
3:   2   1
4:   3   2
5:   3   2
6:   4   2
```

Here, `group` corresponds to `n=2.` Thank you!

Comment: `DT[, group := ((.I - 1) %/% n) + 1]` will work based on what you show for any `n` greater than 0, but if the behavior needs to change based on whether or not `var` is consecutive you need to provide an example and explanation of what happens when `var` is **not** consecutive.

Comment: @GregorThomas Thanks for your comment. I should have been more specific my apologies. The `var` variable will always be strictly positive. However, I should have noted that there could be repeated values of `var`. But your solution still works great. Thank you very much.

Comment: I mean, it seems like the values of `var` don't matter at all. And my solution doesn't use them at all.

Comment: Sorry for my comment, @akrun, I don't wish malice and mis-interpreted some of the code. While we discussed it, I found corner cases that highlighted the differences in our approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we can use `findInterval` for this:

```r
DT <- data.table(var = c(1L, 1:10))

n <- 2
DT[, group := findInterval(var, seq(min(var), max(var) + n, by = n))]
#       var group
#     <int> <int>
#  1:     1     1
#  2:     1     1
#  3:     2     1
#  4:     3     2
#  5:     4     2
#  6:     5     3
#  7:     6     3
#  8:     7     4
#  9:     8     4
# 10:     9     5
# 11:    10     5

n <- 3
DT[, group := findInterval(var, seq(min(var), max(var) + n, by = n))]
#       var group
#     <int> <int>
#  1:     1     1
#  2:     1     1
#  3:     2     1
#  4:     3     1
#  5:     4     2
#  6:     5     2
#  7:     6     2
#  8:     7     3
#  9:     8     3
# 10:     9     3
# 11:    10     4
```

(The `+n` in the call to `seq` is so that we always have a little more than we need; if we did just `seq(min(.),max(.),by=n)`, it would be possible the highest values of `var` would be outside of the sequence. One could also do `c(seq(min(.), max(.), by=n), Inf)` for the same effect.)